# I would like assistance with the Glim macro describes by Thompson and Baker un their 1981 paper

Tags: parameters, estimation

I would like to recode this macro in visualbasic for Excel. Thanks anticipated

I've been studying the problem and the Glim macro to no avail. In particular I've found difficult to understand how to use the model variates